# Merge Multiples Dataframes preserving columns and filling with NaN the rest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a set of data frames `df1, df2, ... dfn`

dfs are is like:

```
 id  |    date    | metric_value
001  | 2013-01-01 |     0.73
001  | 2013-03-01 |     0.73
002  | 2013-01-01 |     0.73
002  | 2013-02-01 |     0.73
```

But there is not necessarily a match between the `id` and `date` column, so I could have a df1 like:

```
 id  |    date    | metric_value1
001  | 2013-01-01 |     0.73
001  | 2013-03-01 |     0.73
002  | 2013-01-01 |     0.73
002  | 2013-02-01 |     0.73
004  | 2013-03-01 |     0.73
```

And a df2 like:

```
id   |    date    | metric_value2
001  | 2013-01-01 |     0.72
003  | 2013-02-01 |     0.72
003  | 2013-03-01 |     0.72
004  | 2013-01-01 |     0.72
```

How could I merge df1 and df2, generally speaking `df1 ... dfn`, so I could have something like:

```
id   |    date    | metric_value1  | metric_value2
001  | 2013-01-01 |     0.73       |       0.72
001  | 2013-02-01 |      Nan       |       Nan
001  | 2013-03-01 |     0.73       |       Nan
002  | 2013-01-01 |     0.73       |       Nan
002  | 2013-02-01 |     0.73       |       Nan
002  | 2013-03-01 |      Nan       |       Nan
003  | 2013-01-01 |      Nan       |       Nan
003  | 2013-02-01 |      Nan       |       0.72
003  | 2013-03-01 |      Nan       |       0.72
004  | 2013-01-01 |      Nan       |       0.72
004  | 2013-02-01 |      Nan       |       Nan
004  | 2013-03-01 |     0.73       |       Nan
```

To cover all Ids, in the entire range of date, from min date, to max date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @JonathanLeon solution a little further:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data='''id|date|metric_value1
001|2013-01-01|0.73
001|2013-03-01|0.73
002|2013-01-01|0.73
002|2013-02-01|0.73
004|2013-03-01|0.73'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='|', engine='python')

data='''id|date|metric_value2
001|2013-01-01|0.72
003|2013-02-01|0.72
003|2013-03-01|0.72
004|2013-01-01|0.72'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='|', engine='python')

df_out = df1.merge(df2, on=['id', 'date'], how='outer')

df_out['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_out['date'])

df_out.set_index(['id', 'date'])\
      .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_out['id'].unique(),
                                           df_out['date'].unique()],
                                          names=['id', 'date']))\
      .sort_index()
      .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    id       date  metric_value1  metric_value2
0    1 2013-01-01           0.73           0.72
1    1 2013-02-01            NaN            NaN
2    1 2013-03-01           0.73            NaN
3    2 2013-01-01           0.73            NaN
4    2 2013-02-01           0.73            NaN
5    2 2013-03-01            NaN            NaN
6    3 2013-01-01            NaN            NaN
7    3 2013-02-01            NaN           0.72
8    3 2013-03-01            NaN           0.72
9    4 2013-01-01            NaN           0.72
10   4 2013-02-01            NaN            NaN
11   4 2013-03-01           0.73            NaN
```

Comment: Awesome!! That is really what I wanted. Does this code can be generalized to N number of dfs, each one with a differente metric_values?  Could I merge N datframes this way?

Comment: Merge only works two dataframes at a time.  You can use join to join many dataframes but you'll have to move your "joining" columns into the index first for all dataframes.

Comment: Does it work if I get the df_out and merge with a df3, and keep doing that so on so forth with the N data frames? How this move your "joining" columns into the index first for all dataframes would be?

Comment: Yes, you can merge df_out with df3 and so on and on.  But you could do it all at once if you use join.   df1.join([df2,df3,...]) if the indexes are aligned properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data='''id|date|metric_value1
001|2013-01-01|0.73
001|2013-03-01|0.73
002|2013-01-01|0.73
002|2013-02-01|0.73
004|2013-03-01|0.73'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='|', engine='python')

data='''id|date|metric_value2
001|2013-01-01|0.72
003|2013-02-01|0.72
003|2013-03-01|0.72
004|2013-01-01|0.72'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='|', engine='python')

df1.merge(df2, on=['id', 'date'], how='outer')
```

Output:

```
   id        date  metric_value1  metric_value2
0   1  2013-01-01          0.730          0.720
1   1  2013-03-01          0.730            NaN
2   2  2013-01-01          0.730            NaN
3   2  2013-02-01          0.730            NaN
4   4  2013-03-01          0.730            NaN
5   3  2013-02-01            NaN          0.720
6   3  2013-03-01            NaN          0.720
7   4  2013-01-01            NaN          0.720
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
import datetime

#build your list of unique ids
ids = pandas.concat([df1['id'], df2['id']])
ids = pandas.Series(ids.unique())

#can do as above to get all possible dates, I've just generated them.
dates = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.date_range(datetime.date.today(), freq='D', periods = 10), columns=['date'])

#use merge to generate the cartesian product of all dates and all ids
combinations = pandas.merge(left=dates, right=pandas.DataFrame(ids.unique(), columns=['id']), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

#merge your dataframes on your 'key' columns
df3 = pandas.merge(left=dates, right=df1, on=['date', 'id'], how='left')
df4 = pandas.merge(left=dates, right=df2, on=['date', 'id'], how='left')
```